# Local Maven repo requires sudo to resolve artifacts via gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-maven-plugin

I've recently migrated from the `maven-android-plugin` to v1.1 of the Gradle-based Android build system. After a number of changes associated with hamcrest (and associated generics hell) I have my *Robolectric* based unit tests running under gradle... but only if I run the testing gradle commands with `sudo`.

The error I get back having run a command akin to `./gradlew testWithGoogleMapsDebug`

```
Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.MultipleArtifactsNotFoundException: Missing:
```

I've checked the local `.m2` repo's permissions and `chmod -R 777`'ed the root of the repo to see if that has any affect (it didn't).

I suspect someone out there knows whats up but alas I'm a bit stuck!

...here is the full trace;

```
Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
----------
1) org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup -DartifactId=tagsoup -Dversion=1.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup -DartifactId=tagsoup -Dversion=1.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
    2) org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2

2) org.json:json:jar:20080701

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.json -DartifactId=json -Dversion=20080701 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.json -DartifactId=json -Dversion=20080701 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
    2) org.json:json:jar:20080701

3) org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.3_r2-robolectric-0

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=android-all -Dversion=4.3_r2-robolectric-0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=android-all -Dversion=4.3_r2-robolectric-0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
    2) org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.3_r2-robolectric-0

----------
```

...and here is the app build.gradle with sensitive information removed;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        // Keep original packaging package path.
        applicationId "my.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 25
        versionName "2.4.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }

        release {
            // Release signing detail.
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            pseudoLocalesEnabled true
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        withGoogleMaps {
            // Flavour-based config
        }

        withOsm {
            // Flavour-based config
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':viewPagerIndicator')
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
    compile 'de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.1.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'

    withGoogleMapsCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'
    withGoogleMapsCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.0.0'
    withOsmCompile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.1'
    withOsmCompile 'org.osmdroid:osmbonuspack:4.4'
    withOsmCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.7'

    // Test dependencies.
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
    testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'

    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
}

configurations {
    // Avoid gradle warnings.
    all*.exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    all*.exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
```

...and I'm running Maven 3.1.1;

```
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 16:22:22+0100)
Maven home: /Users/me/Dropbox/Maven
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: what about maven's `settings.xml`? is it `chmod 777`'ed as well?

Comment: Hi there, @arghtype, I did also do this but with no effect. May I need to clean gradle's caches down or something between these attempts?

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows - here you go! http://pastebin.com/4brVrtpT

Comment: @OceanLife Post in your question. Also, there are so weird versioning issues, you are compiling with an older SDK. Have you tried just deleting your `.m2` folder? Also do not use `mavenLocal()` unless you are bringing in your own custom library.

Comment: Thanks for your interest Jared. Yes, this is me breathing new life into an android-maven-plugin project that's a couple of years old. I've been migrating it over to Gradle and have a number of modules not specified here residing within my local repo (the one used for the maven-android-plugin). I'll update Android's compilation level, surprised if this would affect test dependency resolution?

Comment: Bumped compile/target versions to 5.0.1 (API level 21) with no effect. Haven't tried simply deleting the repo... was hoping to understand what Gradle is having an issue is but will attempt next.

Comment: removed ````mavenLocal()```` dependency by relying directly on the custom jars and aars... same error unfortunately. Next upgrading the build tooling to see if this is related to the ````mavenLocal()```` c*ck up of a few releases back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... running the build with the `--info` flag highlighted that gradle is trying to create a `.m2` folder at the root of the hard drive. It doesn't have permission to do that (why would it?!).

So, the "WTF" moment was why when running unit tests under a gradle build does it need *another* .m2 repo at the root of the drive. Lost on that...

Comment: I would say thats a Gradle bug or a misconfiguration in your setup somewhere. In fact Gradle should not need or use a Maven repository at all since it uses its own cache in .gradle.

Comment: Thanks @ManfredMoser - I will keep an eye out for anything awry. Also, may I take this opportunity to thank you for the monumental effort on the ````android-maven-plugin```` - it is a great product.